# Is there a simple way to verify if a file has been uploaded correctly to Amazon S3?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I use the tpyo Amazon S3.php class from https://github.com/tpyo/amazon-s3-php-class to upload files like this:

```
# START AMAZON S3
$s3 = new S3('KEY', 'SECRET');
$uploadfile = 'user-' . $uid . '/' . $new_file;
S3::putObject(
    S3::inputFile('/home/username/www/images/'.$uid.'/'.$file_name, false),
    'bucketname',
    $uploadfile,
    S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ,
    array(),
    array(),
    S3::STORAGE_CLASS_STANDARD
);
#END AMAZON S3
```

I've noticed that out of maybe 10,000 files that are uploading, it fails to upload maybe 10 or 20 for various reasons like network problems, server problems, etc. Is there any way to easily verify if the file has been uploaded correctly?

The solution I found is to grab the image with a class like this:

```
function ranger($url){
    $headers = array(
    "Range: bytes=0-983040"
    );

    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $data = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $data;
}
```

And then check the dimensions of the image and know it exists if the width and the height are `>1`, but this method is really slow especially for big images.

I see no class built into the tpyo S3.php file to verify if the file exists. Anybody has a better idea?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm so stupid. There's an option called `getObjectInfo`.